# COUNTIF finds dates equal to, but not greater than or equal to

Tags: excel-formula, countif

=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,date_start) is equal to 1,000 which is correct
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,">=" & date_start) is giving me a result of 0

I have checked the formats of the cells and everything matches.  I am confused why the results for ">=" and "<=" do not produce any results

The date_start is a named range (a single cell) and in this scenario is equal to 2019-01-01 (yyyy-mm-dd).  All other dates are 2019-01-01 or after (2019-01-02....)

Comment: Just because the "formats" are the same does not make the date a  true date.  It can be a string that looks like a date, this could cause the issue.

Comment: This was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the date cells in Column A, as well as the start date to a recognizable format and your formula should work. Ctrl +1 ... "date", then choose a format.